# html: how to redirect traffic to a different web address?

Tags: html

html:  how to automatically redirect traffic from my webspace to a different web address using HTML?
I am new to this.  I and am just trying to redirect traffic from my webspace to a Facebook page.  iTunes does not allow my Facebook page address to be placed there due to it's length. So I need a relay buffer.  If there is an easier way of doing this let me know.

Thanks

Comment: if iTunes is complaining about the URL length have you tried a url shortener like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use a meta refresh element:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.facebook.com/<url>">
```

Or a javascript redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.facebook.com/<url>"</script>
```

Or a HTACCESS redirect:

```
Redirect / http://www.facebook.com/<url>
```

Or use an iframe.

But personally, I'd use the short facebook URL, something like http://www.facebook.com/cnn. This should be short enough for iTunes.

Comment: I am new to this.  The webspace allows "html" and some other Microsoft products, but I am using a MAC. The "html file" that I upload to the webspace is all I have to work with.  I tried the examples but when I click on the file, I just see the text and no redirect.  appreciating the help

Comment: Try surrounding either of the first two (I recommend the first) with <html> ... </html>, and make sure the file is named properly, e.g. index.html . I still recommend the facebook short-url approach, but any will work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://facebook.com/" />
```